# How to validate fromDate , toDate using <sx:datetimepicker> in struts2?

Tags: validation, struts2, datetimepicker

I am using following code for fromDate and toDate in Jsp(struts2 application).

```
<s:label value="valid From* "/>
<sx:datetimepicker required="true" name="validFrom" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"  />
<s:label value="Valid To * :" />
<sx:datetimepicker required="true" name="validTo" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

Its is generating date in the specified format. I want to check the selected date values and if Todate is less than Fromdate have to show error message.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most straight forward way is to implement Validateable which is probably easiest to do by extending ActionSupport. Note I changed "validFrom" to simply "from" and "validTo" to simply "to" in the following.

Then in your action you would write...

```
//Not tested
public void Validate(){
   //it is obvious that if one of these conditions is true the other will be as well
   //this is just to show the typical case of building up multiple field errors
   if (to.before(from)){
      addFieldError("to", getText("To date must be later than from date."));
   }
   if (from.after(to)){
      addFieldError("from", getText("From date must be before to date."));
   }
}
```

Since I like to opt for the simple theme you'll find you can get the field errors with http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/fielderror.html in case you want more control over where the error messages are placed.

For more information on validation please see: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html